# Is Zirconium 3+ ion more stable than Zr?

Tags: electronic-configuration

Is $\ce{Zr^{3+}}$ more stable than the atom, and why if yes?

Comment: And what is your question supposed to mean? Do we need to make a filter for "stable" in titles for automatic flagging as unclear?

Comment: Not sure how else I can ask: Is Zirconium 3+ ion more stable than Zr? Stable as in "electronic configuration". Is that really that unclear from the ion formula?

Comment: "Stable as in "electronic configuration"." is meaningless. You don't know the context in which you want to ask so there's no question.

Comment: You can't compare a neutral atom to an ion. That doesn't make sense between you're not comparing two systems that have the same components.

Comment: I cannot tell that to the teachers who designed the course. I am expected to explain which is more stable. This is the assignment. Sorry if this not satisfactory to your high standards, but I have no choice in formulating the question or answering it in any other terms than expected.

Answer (score 3):

I think your main confusion lies in the statements "most common" and "most stable".  These statements are not equivalent.

The "most common" statement implies the conditions found in nature, meaning the different conditions where it is found or where it was formed.

The term "most stable" *requires* that you specify a set of conditions explicitly.  In the presence of one set of conditions one for will be the most stable, and under another set of conditions another form will be most stable.